# Limit proof by the definition

Tags: real-analysis

> If $X=(x_n)$ is a positive sequence which converges to $x$, then
>   $(\sqrt {x_n})$ converges to $\sqrt x$.

The hint my book provided is: $$\sqrt x_n -\sqrt x = \frac{x_n-x}{\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x}$$
which I would never even guessed to try, so maybe I am not totally understanding what the limit defintion is trying to convey.

My attempt:

We know that $\lim x_n=x$. So, given any $\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ an $N$ such that $|x_n−x|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N.$

Then for $\lim \sqrt {x_n}=\sqrt x$. Given any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that $|\sqrt x_n -\sqrt x|<\epsilon$, $\forall n\ge N$ $$|\sqrt x_n -\sqrt x|=\frac{|x_n-x|}{|\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x|}< \frac{\epsilon}{|\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x|}.$$

Which I don't quite think is correct because I feel like I am missing a lot of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a good track. Now all you need to do is bound $\sqrt {x_n}+\sqrt x$ from **below**. Say you obtain a constant $\frac 1 \eta$ such that $$\frac 1 \eta<\sqrt {x_n}+\sqrt x$$ for each $n$. Then you'll have for each $n$ that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt {x_n}+\sqrt x}<\eta$$

which means

$$\frac {|x_n-x|}{\sqrt {x_n}+\sqrt x}< \eta{\epsilon} $$

Thus, given $\epsilon$ you could take $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|x-x_n|<\epsilon/\eta$ which would leave you with

$$\frac {|x_n-x|}{\sqrt {x_n}+\sqrt x}< \eta{\epsilon/\eta}=\epsilon$$

and the proof would be complete.

Can you do that?

Thomas has a nice solution when $\lim x_n\neq 0$. If $\lim x_n=0$, we'd have to prove that $\sqrt {x_n}<\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough, i.e $x_n<\epsilon^2$ for $x$ large enough. And that is not hard! =)

**ADD** You say "...which I would never even guessed to try, so maybe I am not totally understanding what the limit defintion is trying to convey." The "trick" the book used might not be too obvious at first, but you'll get used to them later. It has nothing to do with understanding the definition of limit wants to convey. What you might want to note is that since we know we can make $|x-x_n|$ small, it would be good to write $|\sqrt x-\sqrt{x_n}|$ in terms of $|x-x_n|$, and work with that. For example, say $x_n\to x$. If you want to prove $x_n^2\to x^2$, you want $$|x^2-x_n^2|$$ small. Yet again, we have $$|x^2-x_n^2|=|x-x_n|\cdot|x+x_n|$$

One part we can make small, the other we can "control" in some way, so we know all in all the product will be small. I think I told you this before: practice, practice, practice.

Comment: I think this is what I am having trouble conveying. When you said it has to be bounded by **below**, why isn't $$\frac{\epsilon}{|\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x|}$$ bounded?

Comment: @Q.matin The problem is not that the above isn't bounded, but that it depends on $n$. Just like when proving continuity of a function, we want to eliminate dependence on $x$.

Comment: Ahh I see. So in all cases it should always be independent? Thus I can bounded it by $$\frac{\epsilon}{|\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x|}<\frac{\epsilon}{|\sqrt x|}.$$ which then completes the proof?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Then you take $N$ such that $|x-x_n|<\sqrt x \epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. Note that this is saying $\sqrt {x_n} $ goes faster to $\sqrt x$ than $x_n$ goes to $x$, since we need less tight bounds!

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot, Peter !

Comment: @Q.matin Note that all you have in the denominator is assumed to be positive, so the absolute value bars are pretty redundant.

Comment: Gotcha, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Q.matin I added something to the answer.

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I needed to hear. Makes things much more clear now. Thanks a lot! I am going to be practicing some more now. :)

Answer (score 2):

First assume that $x\neq 0$.

Given $x$ you can pick $N$ such that when $n\geq N$ then 
$$
\lvert x_n - x\lvert < \epsilon\sqrt{x}.
$$
So then

$$
\lvert\sqrt x_n -\sqrt x\rvert = \frac{|x_n-x|}{|\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x|} = \frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt x_n +\sqrt x} \leq \frac{\lvert x_n - x\rvert}{\sqrt{x}} <  \epsilon.
$$
Here you are just using that $\sqrt{x_n} \geq 0$ for all $n$.

For completion let us now consider the case where $x = 0$. Then you have again $\epsilon > 0$ given. You pick $N$ such that $\lvert x_n\rvert = x_n< \epsilon^2$. So then
$$
\lvert \sqrt{x_n}\rvert = \sqrt{x_n} < \sqrt{\epsilon^2} = \epsilon.
$$

Comment: Care should be taken if it happens that $\lim x_n=x=0$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Did I manage to fix it?